# Rails 3: Absolute URLs to resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, omniauth, absolute-path

I'm using the devise Gem for Facebook auth.
Trying to get the resource of the devise URL to be absolute so I don't have to change it
when switching from environments.

```
<%= user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook) %> == gives ==> /auth/facebook
```

adding "root_path" in front gives me

```
<%= root_url %><%= user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook) %>

http://localhost:3000//auth/facebook  (double slash?)
```

I've tried adding this to `url_for` and `link_to` but no luck.

Any ideas?

I'm looking to get

```
http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook
```

and all I have is the "user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook)" resource to play with

Answer (score 2):

```
<%= user_omniauth_authorize_url(:facebook) %>
```

Comment: Sadly I don't think Devise makes this, I'm getting an "undefined method `user_omniauth_authorize_url' for #<#<Class"

Answer (score 1):

Quickly looking through the [OmniAuth](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3a-Overview) page, there doesn't seem to be a user_omniauth_authorize_url method. If you aren't able to find an out-of-the-box solution, I would just create a helper method absolutize_path, which prepends your host part to the path part.

```
def absolutize_path path
  File.join root_url, path
end
```

You could alternately look into using [URI.join](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/uri/rdoc/classes/URI.html#M009388), which is more semantic, but possibly overkill for you need.